# The template for displaying woocommerce product archives looks different between being logged in and logged out of Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason the archive for the woocommerce products looks different between being logged in and logged out.

[Logged in products display in four columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENKJm.png)

[Logged out and the products display in two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYO22.png)

Logged in this is the correct styling coming from the woocommerce plugin:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 22.05%;
}
```

Logged out and this style gets added on top also coming from the plugin:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page[class*="columns-"] ul.products li.product, .woocommerce[class*="columns-"] ul.products li.product {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 2.992em;
}
```

Not sure where this extra styling is coming from. Why does it only add it when Im logged out of Wordpress. The template for the archive Im getting from here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/archive-product.php. I modified it to work with my theme.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<div class="row page-content">
    <?php get_template_part('partials/topnav'); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('partials/banner'); ?>


            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 secondary">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
            ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
            ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: Also just realized im using woocommerce version 2.6.14 and wordpress version 4.9.9

Comment: Incase anyone is wondering the W3 Total Cache plugin is messing up the styling. When I deactivated it the problem was fixed. Ill have to go in a mess around with settings.

Comment: You have to tell W3 Total Cache not to minfiy the CSS for the Woocommerce pages such as the shop page. More info here: https://www.webnots.com/how-to-make-woocommerce-work-with-w3-total-cache/